# Create Query using another Query result as Parameter

Tags: php, postgresql

My problem is:  Use query results shown into as parameters to another query. 
For better understanding here my *index* text:

```
                            <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="pt-br" xml:lang="pt-br">

   <head>
    <title>Alpha</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS.css">  
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.history.js"></script>  
   </head>

<body>

    <form id="searchbox" method="post">
        <label for="sectname"></label>
        <input id="sectname" name="sectname" type="search" placeholder="Busca" class="searchbox" />
        <div style="text-align:center">
            <input id="submit" type="submit" class="button" value="BUSCA"/>
        </div>
    </form>     

    <!--<div class="cardpage" name="cardpage">
    </div>
    -->

    <div class="pic-container">
            <div class="carddata2">
            CONTATOS
            </div>
        <div class="pic-row" >

            <?php
            if (isset($_POST['sectname'])){ 
                    require 'QueryPHP2.php';
            }
            ?>

        </div>  
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Inside the ***div cardpage*** an structure similar to that into ***pic-container*** will be created, requiring, for example, *queryphp0.php*. 
And here is my *queryphp2.php*:

```
<?php

 $host        = "host=localhost";
 $port        = "port=5432";
 $dbname      = "dbname=Cards";
 $credentials = "user=postgres password=12345678";
 $db = pg_connect( "$host $port $dbname $credentials"  );

 if(!$db){
    echo nl2br ("Error : Unable to open database\n");
} 
 $search = $_POST['sectname'];
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM Cards WHERE nome iLIKE $1 OR ramal iLIKE $1 OR    numero iLIKE $1 or email iLIKE $1 OR setor iLIKE $1";

  pg_prepare($db, "my_query", $sql);
 $ret = pg_execute($db, "my_query", array("%".$search."%"));
 $vect = pg_num_rows($ret);

 if(pg_num_rows($ret)<1){
  echo "<div class='carddata2'>";
  echo "NENHUM RESULTADO";
  echo "</div>";
 } else{

 $Nvect=array();
 $i=0;

 while($row = pg_fetch_assoc($ret)){ //Shows User Data Search Result


    $Nvect[$i] = $row['idcard'];
    $i++;
    echo "<div class='carddata'>";
    echo "<img src='".$row['pic']."'class='cardcontent2'/>";
    echo nl2br ($row['nome'] . "\n");
  echo "</div>";
 echo "</div>";
 }

  pg_close($db);
 }
?>
```

I was able to retrieve query resulting ***ID*** (PK of my *cards* table) and save it inside a array (it's position is managed by the *i* variable created). I want to use this variable as *clickable* and the content should be usable by my second query. 
I'm open to any suggested changes, improvements and even "Why on earth would you do this stuff?".

Comment: So what you're trying to say is you want to create a button that will have a dynamic parameter?

Comment: I think you were able to simplify my question a LOT! Thanks. I'm pretty new to this, sorry about the mess.